# Changing screens from a Spinner on_text problem

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, spinner

I'm wanting to create a type of workflow using ScreenManager that progresses as options are selected. I have several screens defined within ScreenManager and within one screen I have created a Spinner with several options. I'm wanting to call a Function from the on_text and pass the selected Spinner value, perform a task based on the passed value and then move to the next screen in the workflow.

I've created a Function inside a class (Screen) with only a print() for testing purposes. When I select an option from the Spinner nothing happens.

I've only provided what I think is the relevant code...

kv file:

```
<HomeScreen>:
    name: 'homeScreen'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        Label:
            id: 'home'
            text: 'Home Screen'


<NewSession>:
    name: 'newSession'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            id: new
            text: 'Create New Session'

        Spinner:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 25
            id: category
            font_size: 12
            text: "Food Category" #default value showed
            values: ["Beef","Pork","Poultry", "Fish"] #list of values to show
            on_text: root.SelectCut(category.text)

        Widget:


<CurrentSession>:
    id: cs
    name: 'currentSession'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            id: cSession
            text: root.cSession

<History>:
    name: 'history'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            id: 'history'
            text: 'History Data Screen'

<ScreenManagement>:
    HomeScreen:
    NewSession:
    CurrentSession:
    History:

<AllScreen>:

    orientation: 'vertical'
    ScreenManagement:
        id: sm
    BoxLayout:

        size_hint_y: None
        height: 60
        spacing: 5
        padding: 5, 5, 0, 5

        Button:
            text: 'Home'
            on_press: root.ids.sm.current = 'homeScreen'
        Button:
            text: 'New Session'
            on_press: root.ids.sm.current = 'newSession'
        Button:
            text: 'Current Session'
            on_press: 
                root.ids.sm.current = 'currentSession'
        Button:
            text: 'History'
            on_press: root.ids.sm.current = 'history'
```

py file:

```
Builder.load_file("screenLayout.kv")

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class NewSession(Screen):

    def SelectCut(self, text):
        print("In Select Cut")
        print("Food Category: " + text)
        self.sm.current = 'homeScreen'

class CurrentSession(Screen):
    pass

class History(Screen):
    pass

class AllScreen(BoxLayout):
    pass

class WorkingTestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = AllScreen()
        return self.root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WorkingTestApp().run()
```

I'm not able to figure out why nothing is happening when a selection is made from the Spinner and I'm not sure what the syntax will be from within the Function to move to the next screen.

---

Update:
Current code (minus imports)

kv:

```
<HomeScreen>:
    name: 'homeScreen'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        Label:
            id: 'home'
            text: 'Home Screen'

<NewSession>:
    name: 'newSession'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            id: new
            text: 'Create New Session'

        Spinner:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 25
            id: category
            font_size: 12
            text: "Food Category" #default value showed
            values: ["Beef","Pork","Poultry", "Fish"] #list of values to show
            on_text: root.SelectCategory()

        Widget:

<SelectCut>:
    name: 'selectCut'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            id: 'cut'
            text: 'Select Cut Screen'

        Widget:

<CurrentSession>:
    name: 'currentSession'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            id: cSession
            text: 'Current Session Screen'

<History>:
    name: 'history'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            id: 'history'
            text: 'History Data Screen'

<ScreenManagement>:
    HomeScreen:
    NewSession:
    SelectCut:
    CurrentSession:
    History:

<AllScreen>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ScreenManagement:
        id: sm
    BoxLayout:

        size_hint_y: None
        height: 60
        spacing: 5
        padding: 5, 5, 0, 5

        Button:
            text: 'Home'
            on_press: root.ids.sm.current = 'homeScreen'
        Button:
            text: 'New Session'
            on_press: root.ids.sm.current = 'newSession'
        Button:
            text: 'Current Session'
            on_press: 
                root.ids.sm.current = 'currentSession'
        Button:
            text: 'History'
            on_press: root.ids.sm.current = 'history'
```

py:

```
Builder.load_file("screenLayout.kv")

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class NewSession(Screen):
    # This Function isn't executing consistently.
    def SelectCategory(self):
        print("Food Category: " + self.ids.category.text)
        self.manager.current = 'selectCut'

class SelectCut(Screen):
    pass

class CurrentSession(Screen):
    pass

class History(Screen):
    pass

class AllScreen(BoxLayout):
    pass

class WorkingTestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = AllScreen()
        return self.root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WorkingTestApp().run()
```

Comment: In your `SelectCut()` method, just add `self.manager.current = 'someScreenName'`. Where `someScreenName` is the name of one of your `Screens`.

Comment: Your `SelectCut()` method should be executed when your `Spinner` text changes. If it is not being called, there must be something else in your code that you have not posted.

Comment: I've updated my original post to include the full py file (minus imports) and kv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your spinner's `on_text: root.SelectCut(self, text)` to `on_text: root.SelectCut()` the in your .py change `def SelectCut(self, text):` to `def SelectCut(self):` then to change the text you can use `self.ids.category.text` to read or alter the spinner's text and add `root.ids.sm.current = 'your screen'` to this function as well

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, it has gotten me closer.

One odd behavior I'm seeing is I can select an option from the Spinner and now go to a new screen however, if I go back to select a different option, the originally selected option of defaulted on the Spinner and if I select something different nothing happens initially. If I keep trying different selections eventually it seems to recognize the change.

Comment: If you post your updated code in a "Update:" section beneath what's already in your question and I'll see what I can do for this issue

Comment: also in your .kv, ```<ScreenManagement>:
    HomeScreen:
    NewSession:
    CurrentSession:
    History:``` isnt needed you should add something like ```screen_manager = ScreenManager()
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenOne(name="screenOne"))
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return screen_manager``` to your .py file instead so that screenmanager handles everything directly from the app's class

Comment: Bob - I appreciate your input and patience. When I implemented your suggestion regarding eliminating <ScreenManagement>: and using the .add_widget I lost the bottom menu bar that wrapped all of the screens.

I'll update my original post with the current code I'm trying to use... I reverted back to what I had originally.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with your buttons/screens so I know more of what theyre each supposed to do? Like a quick walkthrough of how it should function when you open the app til it does everything you want as Im not sure what the SelectCut Screen is for or what is supposed to happen with the on_text event

Comment: Reply Part 1:
The main screen is nothing more than a starting point. The buttons on the bottom are intended to allow for consistent screen access from any point in the app without having to copy/paste the kivy syntax for those buttons into each screen definition.

The 'Home' button serves as a type of 'cancel' button if you are in the middle of a workflow and decide you don't want to continue, or you're on one of the other bottom button screens.

Comment: Reply Part 2: The 'New Session' button starts a workflow consisting of several screens. The first prompting you to select a category from a list (Spinner) which will be used to determine the next list of selectable options. After making the second selection the next screen will display the previous two selections and prompt you for user input text. The next screen will display all information for the new session to create and include a 'Start' button. When the session is started all of the information will be saved to a SQLite database and ....

Comment: Reply Part 3: ... and session information will be saved to the database on a regular interval.

The 'Current Session' button will display the most recent entry in the database for the current session.
The 'History' button will display past sessions and allow you to view details of those sessions.

I have most of the back-end functionality written in another project and I'm trying to get the screen flow working so I can incorporate the back-end code. Not all of the screens have been created, I'm creating each one as I make progress.

Comment: well if you get stuck later on put a post up and I can help since it sounds like it's still a WIP. In regards to the spinner option not triggering an event everytime ```on_text``` only works if the text/option changes so in your NewSession class make this your new function so the spinner goes back to default everytime and the screen to whichever one you are wanting. ```def SelectCategory(self):
        print("Food Category: " + self.ids.category.text)
        self.ids.category.text = 'Food Category'
        self.manager.current = 'currentSession'```

Comment: Bob - Thanks for helping me straighten a few things out.